# SQLite multiple tables of same class

Tags: sqlite, class, windows-phone-8.1

In Windows phone app, I created a Student class. I created a table using that Student class. Now I want to create another table using the same class Student. What I want to do is maintain separate tables for each group of students. How  can I do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on why you need to do this? Normally group membership would be done with a table to represent the groups, and another to represent the membership of groups by (in your case) students.

Comment: Just Change the Name of the table..